# fileSystem object is null or undefined using phonegap-2.3.0 in windows phone 7

Tags: ajax, cordova, jquery-mobile

In our app, we are reading a file to get message details using phonegap filesystem. It mostly works in android, but in windows phone 7 frequently the filesystem gets "null or undefined" when i read the same file. I will paste my code below for reference.

```
this.getMessageContent = function(){
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFileSystemSuccess, onProcessFailure);
};


function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem){
    fileSystem.root.getFile("/app/www/Notifications.txt", null, gotFileEntry, onProcessFailure);
    console.log("File system name"+fileSystem.name);
    console.log("File root name"+fileSystem.root.name);
}


function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(readFileContent, onProcessFailure);
}


 function readFileContent(file) {
    console.log("File Size-->"+file.size);
    console.log("File url-->"+file.fullPath);
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        console.log("Read as text");
        var contentLength = evt.target.result;
        if(evt.target.result){
            console.log("File Content Non-Empty-->"+evt.target.result);
        }else{
            console.log("File Content Empty-->"+evt.target.result);
        }
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
}


function onProcessFailure(e) {
  var msg = '';

  switch (e.code) {
    case FileError.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR:
      msg = 'QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR';
      break;
    case FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
      msg = 'NOT_FOUND_ERR';
      break;
    case FileError.SECURITY_ERR:
      msg = 'SECURITY_ERR';
      break;
    case FileError.INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR:
      msg = 'INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR';
      break;
    case FileError.INVALID_STATE_ERR:
      msg = 'INVALID_STATE_ERR';
      break;
    default:
      msg = 'Unknown Error';
      break;
  };

  console.log('Notification File Related Error: ' + msg);
}
```

The above code sometime works fine, sometime throws following error

```
Log:"Error in error callback: File672824422 = TypeError: Unable to get value of the property 'getFile': object is null or undefined"
```

phonegap fileSystem object is getting null or undefined frequently.

I have a link by clicking that i am calling the function this.getMessageContent() to read the file. I can't figure out how filesystem object is getting null or undefined frequently in windows phone7.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to access the file using another method

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('GET', 'Notifications.txt', false);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    if (xhr.status == 200) { 
        console.log(xhr.responseText); 
      }

    }
}

xhr.send(null);
```

Comment: Sorry we are using phonegap, so we need to use phonegap file reading only.